# How to prettify reltuples output in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing this query in Postgres

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

I got that query from this wiki on estimating row counts: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

And the output of that query against my database is

```
  reltuples  
-------------
 8.03065e+07
(1 row)
```

Is there any way I can prettify that output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahh can't believe it's so simple, just cast it:

```
SELECT reltuples::numeric FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

And it becomes

```
 reltuples 
-----------
  80306500
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
SELECT reltuples::float FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

Note: if you use `reltuples::numeric`, last (1-4) digits will be rounded and shown as 0s.